# Get base uri before bootstrap angular 2

Tags: angular

I have to fetch information from the server before I bootstrap my angular 2 application.  I was able to do this with teh ReflectiveInjector and HTTP_PROVIDERS.  My problem is that only works if I hard code the url.  Since this is on many different environments I need to be able to get the base url for my service calls.  In Angular 1 I was able to do this with $injector.get('location') and then call location.path().  I can do something similar after this app has been bootstrapped but when I try to do this using RelectiveInjector I get further and further down a rabbit hole.  The first issue is no Location provider error.  So I add one of those to resolveAndCreate.  Then there is no provider for HasLocationStrategy and on and on.  I was able to get it down to where it would execute but then there is a call to getDom in BrowserPlatformLocation that returns null and that is as far as I could get.  I am hoping somebody can tell me there is an easier way to get Location.path before the app is bootstrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overthinking and forgot to use common sense.  You can just do it with window.location.